# Route 443 and 80 traffic from Hyper-V HostVM to GuestVM

Tags: virtualhost, hyper-v, hyper-virtualization

If someone can help me understanding how to route the 443/80 port traffic received on Host-VM to Guest-VM in Hyper-V server would be appreciated.

[image]

Just to add a point, I have already setup communication between HostVM and GuestVMs and from HostVM I can access these URLs directly, by pointing the GuestVMs- IP and HostURL in HostVM's Host.txt file.

Regards,
Khan